# Jquery Jqmodal window IE position

Tags: jquery-plugins

I fixed the way the content was being pushed down with using the +position:absolute !important; hack that i've found. But now my question is no matter how i style the top (in the jqmWindow in IE it still seems to popup the window in the middle of the page. In FF however i've gotten the page to be more towards the top. The reason why i need to move this jqm window is that there is more info on the div (jqm) then will fit on the screen. Is there a way just to make the window a certain size and have scroll bars on the side if the content is larger? Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

you should be able to wrap the contents of the window in a div and set it's height, as well as overflow

```
div.wrap{
   height:220px;
   overflow:scroll;
}
```

Comment: Sweet Thanks. And for the window position i added +top:1% !important; so in IE i can specify the position of the popup div.